# MS Access Copy single item from Entry, Paste into Next Entry - Inventory Shelf Location

Tags: ms-access

I am completely new to designing MS Access and I haven't found a SIMPLE design to what I am hoping to accomplish.

I need to take a product inventory in my small retail store.

I have named/numbered the shelves.

What I hope to be able to accomplish is enter a shelf location for the first item on that shelf.  Scan the barcode for that item, then enter the quantity of that item.  When I move to another shelf, enter the new shelf number on the item scanning page, then scan the next item and enter quantity.

I am hoping to find an automated copy/paste from the shelf# blank, then copy into the form for the next entry.

My Table only includes 3 columns: SKU, Quantity, Location

Thank you for anyone who can help me with this HOPEFULLY basic task.

Comment: Everything is very clear I think except what the actual question is.  If I understand correctly, you mean that you would like your entry system to automatically retain (i.e. "copy/paste", remember) the shelf # from one entry to the next until you enter a new shelf number.  Correct?

Comment: The question refers to "named/numbered" shelves, "shelf location", "shelf number" and **"shelf# blank"** (?), but then the table has a column named "Location".  Although I already asked for clarification, specifically explain what goes into the [Location] field.  Should it store only the shelf #, the shelf name, shelf name & number, or does location refer to a position on the shelf like an index position?

Comment: If you want a value entered in record to carry into another new record, code in that control's AfterUpdate event to set its DefaultValue property.

Comment: Had a power supply failure in a system which kept me from here.
The location, which I created confusion by also calling shelf number, is the data that I desire to remain in each subsequent scan UNTIL I change the text to another location.  I typically name a location with 4 to 10 alphanumeric characters, such as WSW01 for Warehouse South Wall shelf 01.

I hope to enter into the first blank WSW01, scan the UPC for an item on that shelf, enter the quantity of that item, then repeat for the next item on that shelf.  MS Access would continue entering WSW01 until I change to shelf WSW02, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As June7 explained, you need to set the default value using the after update property. For the [location] control, go to the after update property and select [event procedure]. Under this event enter the code
    Me.location.DefaultValue = Me.location

Assuming location is the name of your field, if not update as required. Good Luck!